Template function specialization controlled by enable_if
Suppose I have a template is_my_tag<T> that resolves into true_type or false_type, depending on T.
struct my_tag;
template<class Tags> struct is_my_tag : std::false_type {};
template<> struct is_my_tag<my_tag> : std::true_type {};
template<class... Tags> struct is_my_tag<std::tuple<my_tag, Tags...>> : std::true_type {};

There exists some template function in the library:
template<class T>
std::string fun(const T& ctx) {
    return "base";
}

I want to specialize it for the types for which is_my_tag<T> == true_type.
I tried this code, but it fails to compile, reporting "ambiguous definition":
template<class T, typename = std::enable_if_t<is_my_tag<T>::value>>
std::string fun(const T& ctx) {
    return "override";
}

What is the correct way to write override, assuming that I have no access to the base definition?
If it matters, I use g++13

it's not overriding, it's overloading

With C++20 subsumption, you might add overload with constraint:
template<class T>
requires is_my_tag<T>::value
std::string fun(const T&) {
    return "override";
}

Demo
For previous version, without changing original, you might add better overload (which mostly duplicate is_my_tag definition)
std::string fun(const my_tag&) {
    return "override";
}
template<class... Tags>
std::string fun(const std::tuple<my_tag, Tags...>&) {
    return "override";
}

Demo
